# Cannot transform XML file to html using XSLT stylesheet

Tags: html, reactjs, .net, xml, xslt-2.0

client side - react js
server side - dot net

XSLT version - 2.0

hi, requirement is to transform an XML file to a html file using an XSLT stylesheet to display to the user in the client side. But problem is I could not find a way to transform it properly.

What I tried so far,

1. Tried linking the stylesheet in the xml file and opening it in the browser so that the transformation will be done by the browser automatically but this did not work as expected. In chrome it's just a blank window and in firefox it displays the text with no styling. I also found out that browsers still do not support xslt 2.0 transformation so I assume that is the issue.

----------------------xml data--------------------------------

Above shows how I linked it. Tried both type="text/xslt" and type="text/xsl".

2. Tried transform in the server side (.net 7 /c#).

   XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
   using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltString))) {
   transform.Load(reader);
   }
   StringWriter results = new StringWriter();
   using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXml))) {
   transform.Transform(reader, null, results);
   }
   return results.ToString();

Above method did not give any error but no content in the resulting file. Later found out that      XslCompiledTransform does not support XSLT 2.0, it only supports 1.0. So I tried a 3rd party library
Saxon-HE.

```
            var xslt = new FileInfo(@"E:\xmltesting\stylesheet-ubl.xslt");
            var input = new FileInfo(@"E:\xmltesting\invoice32.xml");
            var output = new FileInfo(@"E:\xmltesting\test.html");

            var processor = new Processor();
            var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
            var executable = compiler.Compile(new Uri(xslt.FullName));

            var destination = new DomDestination();
            using (var inputStream = input.OpenRead())
            {
                var transformer = executable.Load();
                transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(input.DirectoryName));
                transformer.Run(destination);
            }

            destination.XmlDocument.Save(output.FullName);
```

Above method gives exception at below line,

var executable = compiler.Compile(new Uri(xslt.FullName));

System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile' threw an exception.'
Inner Exception
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions)'.

Could not find much related to this exception.

3. Since transforming from the server-side doesn't look that promising atm moved back to client side transformation. I am currently looking into saxon-js...but still no luck.

Anyone have an idea on how to go about this?. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Saxon-HE is that exactly, are you using it with the .NET framework on Windows or are you trying to use .NET 7 (core) and if so, on which platform are you getting that exception?

Comment: Also, as for trying to use Saxon-HE, do you get that exception with any attempt to run XSLT 2 through it or only with your particular XSLT code?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Saxon-HE version is 10.8.0 and am using it with .NET 7 framework on windows 10 and 11 both

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have tried with only 1 XSLT 2.0 stylesheet which is the one that is needed to transform the xml into the desired html.

Comment: Saxon HE 10 from Saxonica is compatible with the Microsoft .NET framework, the latest version of that is 4.8. NET 7 is no .NET framework but latest (cross platform) .NET Core release, I kind of wonder how you managed to use a .NET framework only package like Saxon HE 10 with .NET 7 at all. As for running the stylesheet through Saxon HE 10.8 on Windows, before writing your own code, have you tried to run it through Saxon's HE .NET command line `Transform.exe -s:input.xml -xsl:ubl.xslt`, to test whether that work?

Comment: @MartinHonnen oh didn't know that it was also a .NET Core release. Maybe that's the issue. I tried with a simple xslt file it still give the same exception. As for the Saxen HE 10 package I got it from Nuget Packages in Visual Studio. If it's not compatible with .net 7 am not sure why it is available. Anyways I will try the command line code you sent. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't get how you would get an exception at that line you say if you really try to use the .NET framework package of Saxon 10 HE with .NET 7; I have tried now and while VS lets you select the package you immediately get warnings and any attempt to run the code for me already gives an exception on any attempt to do e.g. `new Processor();`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen huh strange, my one compiles and executes successfully until it gives an exception at that place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run XSLT 2 or 3 stylesheets with .NET 7 you can do so using the commercial SaxonCS package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SaxonCS, latest versions are 11.5 and 12.0) or using the IKVM cross compiled version of Saxon HE 11.5 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SaxonHE11s9apiExtensions); the following is code using the IKVM cross compiled Saxon HE 11.5 in .NET 7:

```
using net.liberty_development.SaxonHE11s9apiExtensions;
using net.sf.saxon.s9api;

var processor = new Processor(false);

var xsltCompiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();

var xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.Compile(new FileInfo("ubl.xslt"));

var xslt30Transformer = xsltExecutable.load30();

xslt30Transformer.Transform(new FileInfo("invoice-sample.xml"), processor.NewSerializer(new FileInfo("invoice-sample.html")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Martin's answer has shown you the options for running the transformation server-side using Saxon on .NET.

But you also asked about the options for running the transformation client-side in the browser; for that, please take a look at SaxonJS.